# Unity3D Quit Android Game with user prompt

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hi I have a code that quits the game on backspace key on Unity3D,
But I want to give the user a YES/NO Question that he really wants to quit or not ?

Just like this :

[image: Example]

Is there anyway to do this in Unity3D ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with unity's gui attach this to a game object and it should do that
you should make a GUI skin and play around with the components, you can add and tweak the components to your specifications

```
#pragma strict
var count : int = 0;
var skin : GUISkin;
function Update () {
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) { 
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    count = 1;
            }
}
function OnApplicationPause(){
Time.timeScale = 0;
count = 1;

}

function OnGUI(){
if(count == 1){
GUI.skin = skin;


   GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),"Exit");
   GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width*1/4,Screen.height*2/6,Screen.width*2/4,Screen.height*1/6), "Are you sure you want to exit the game?");
if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/4,Screen.height*3/8,Screen.width/2,Screen.height/8),"Yes"))
          {

         Application.Quit();

          }
          if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/4,Screen.height*4/8,Screen.width/2,Screen.height/8),"Keep Playing"))
          {
          count = 0;
          Time.timeScale = 1;
}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I give it a try and let you know the result

Comment: Well, that was nice but need some fixes, thee first and most important problem is that it doesn't pause the game how ever you set TimeScale to 0 !!!! and another problem is that It doesn't show the question above the buttons. Thanks again and waiting for you answer

Comment: i edited i put in onApplicationPause, idk, maybe thats exactly how it is in mine and it pauses perfectly, i added more GUI components, you have to play around with them to get it how you want them

Comment: I have no idea why I should click "Keep Playing" twice to get rid of gui, it seems that it creates two gui

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you'll have to write some kind of plugin to access native Android OS features. There are a few helpful videos on Youtube, on how to build plugins. I'd start here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1Mle2ERiuQ&list=PLf8PfKIJPGkjhMgylU87G5A0JLMSy_8ad

Cheers.

Comment: My bad, thought they wanted an exact replica. Which is entirely possible with plugins, but slight overkill if you only want a dialog box.